# Why does this AngularJS code only work some of the time in Chrome? How do I fix it?

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome

I'm trying to learn Google's "AngularJS" and having difficulty testing in Chrome browser. When I run the page in MSIE it works every time. In Chrome, one of two things happens: only part of the code works, or all of the code works.

I am aware of how to Disable the Chrome cache in Developer Tools, and to leave Developer Tools open while testing.

The "main.ctrl.js" file defines a Title for the page, which renders correctly. The code to update the Employee list only works some of the time. All of this works every time in MS Internet Explorer. Why? Why? Why!!!

app.js

```
angular.module('app', []);
```

main.ctrl.js

```
angular.module('app').controller("EmployeeController", function(){
    var ec= this;

    ec.title = 'Employee List';

    ec.employees = [
        {
            firstName: "John",
            lastName: "Doe",
            office: "Washington D.C."
    }];

    ec.new = {};

    ec.addEmployee = function() {
        ec.employees.push(ec.new);
        ec.new = {};
    };
});
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>AngularJS Tutorial</title>

    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="main.ctrl.js"></script>

</head>

<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="EmployeeController as main">
{{main.title}}

 <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="employee in main.employees">{{employee.firstName}} {{employee.lastName}}, {{employee.office}}</li>
    </ul>

<form class="form" name="main.addForm" ng-submit="main.addEmployee()">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>First Name <input class="form-control" ng-model="main.new.firstName" required type="text" /></label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Last Name <input class="form-control" ng-model="main.new.lastName" required type="text" /></label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Office <input class="form-control" ng-model="main.new.office" required type="text" /></label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6" style='align=center'>
        <button class="btn btn-success"><label class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign">Add</button>
    </div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When you say "works some of the time", do you mean when it doesn't work you have to refresh the page a couple times until it does work?

Comment: Yes, but simply reloading the page rarely solves the problem. And the issue is specific to Chrome. Additionally, the Title is rendered, while the logic to add the employee fails - that is very strange to me. I know the code works and it continues to work in MSIE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The button in your form is not a `submit` button, it's just a regular button, which means the form doesn't know it's supposed to call the ng-submit function when you press it.

Try changing it to something like this and see if that works:

`<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />`

Comment: That seems to solve the problem. I think it's something to do with missing CSS.

I have removed link tags that loaded CSS files (Twitter Bootstrap). I was wondering how such a Button tag would submit the Form, and didn't understand why it works in MSIE without the CSS being loaded.

Comment: Yeah the intermittent working is a real mystery. Javascript is weird sometimes would be my answer.

Comment: Oh really? Well maybe that isn't implemented the same across all the browsers since he or she was having trouble specifically in Chrome.